# TFS Rollback Renamed File Without Manual Intervention to Rename It (TFVC)

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfvc

In TFS 2012 (TFVC), how might I rollback a renamed file to the original filename and contents--without having to manually rename the file (?)

Trying to see if possible just using TFS rollback functionality (e.g., `tf rollback`), not a combination of tf commands or scripted solution.

**SITUATION**

Four steps: 1) Add a file; 2) Check it in; 3) Rename the file and edit the contents; and 4) Check it in:

```
Changeset: 2
Items:
rename, edit $/b.txt

Changeset: 2
Items:
delete, source rename $/a.txt

Changeset: 1
Items:
add $/a.txt
```

I want to rollback to Changeset 1 (a.txt).

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

**Source Control Explorer Rollback:**

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Professional's Source Control Explorer: right-click b.txt > Rollback... > Rollback to a specific version. Specify Changeset 1, then select button Rollback.

This produces the following pending change:

```
Items:
delete, rollback $/b.txt
```

Additionally, a warning appears in Output window:

> TF203066: The rename from $/a.txt to $/b.txt could not be rolled back
>   because you did not provide the source name.  To roll back the rename,
>   undo any pending changes to $/b.txt, and then repeat the operation,
>   but this time include both the source name ($/a.txt) the target name
>   ($/b.txt).

Note: "Rollback to a specific version" doesn't seem to have fields for source and target names.

This seems to indicate rollback doesn't support this scenario (?)

**tf.exe Rollback:**

Command `tf rollback` also doesn't seem to have parameters for source and target names:

> tf rollback /toversion:VersionSpec ItemSpec [/recursive]
>   [/lock:none|checkin|checkout] [/version:versionspec]
>   [/keepmergehistory] [/login:username,[password]] [/noprompt]

When I run the following command, I get the same results as in Visual Studio:

```
C:\test>tf vc rollback /toversion:C1 "$/b.txt" 
delete, rollback:

$/b.txt;C2~C2 -> $/b.txt;C2
```

as well as the same warning as before:

> TF203066: The rename from $/a.txt to
>   $/b.txt could not be rolled back because you did not provide the
>   source name.  To roll back the rename, undo any pending changes to
>   $/b.txt, and then repeat the operation, but this time include both the
>   source name ($/a.txt) the target name ($/b.txt). C:\test>

Note: `tf rename` has parameters `olditem` and `newitem`, which seems to imply warning TF203066 comes from an incomplete call to `tf rename`.

This seems to imply manual intervention will always be required to rename the file (?)

**SOFTWARE VERSIONS**

- Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012 CU4 v11.0.61030.0 (TFVC)
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Professional 15.9.13

**LINKS**

[Rollback Command (Team Foundation Version Control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/rollback-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=azure-devops)

[Rename Command (Team Foundation Version Control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/rename-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=azure-devops)